# Make a text widget with a title and edit button icon

Tags: flutter

I'm tyring to create a widget that looks like this. The box is not editable. It brings up a popup or a dialog like the second picture only when the edit button is clicked. O saves the text. X cancels it. Any idea how someone would go about coding this?

[image]

[image]

i've tried literally everything. textfield, text, but i'm new to flutter. please be patient.

Comment: You can achieve this kind of design with widgets like `Stack`, `Alignment` and `Positioned`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I wrote the code for you and added some explanations here and there:

```
class MyBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyBox({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(), // this is to create a border
        borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.circular(10), // this is to make corners circular
        color: Colors.blue[200],
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: IntrinsicWidth(
          // added this so Align widget doesnt brake stuff and make container stretch. This is rarely needed
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'title',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text('Actual text display\nContinued..\nContinued..'),
              Align(
                // this is to Align the button to the bottom right
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                      // this is to show the dialog popup
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          content: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              color: Colors.blue[200],
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: IntrinsicWidth(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'title',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                        'Actual text display\nContinued..\nContinued..'),
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: [
                                          IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              //save here
                                            },
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.circle_outlined),
                                          ),
                                          IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              //cancel here
                                            },
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.close_rounded),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To actually save data to device memory, I suggest you to use packages like Hive: https://pub.dev/packages/hive

There are great youtube tutorials about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the widget for you. Hope this helps.

```
class PopUpContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const PopUpContainer({super.key});

  @override
  State<PopUpContainer> createState() => _PopUpContainerState();
}

class _PopUpContainerState extends State<PopUpContainer> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.text = 'Actual Text to displayed\ncontinued...\ncontinued...';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      height: 150,
      width: 200,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text(
            "Notes",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Text(controller.text),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  onPressed: () {
                    showBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => Container(
                              height: 200,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                    child: TextField(
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'Edit Text',
                                      ),
                                      controller: controller,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                            setState(() {});
                                          },
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                              Icons.circle_outlined)),
                                      IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                          },
                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.close_rounded))
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ));
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.edit)),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are other widgets to create a popup. You can find them on Flutter Documentation.